# Dialog имеет не максимальную ширину

Tags: java, android, xml

Создаю диалог таким образом

```
private Dialog setDialogWith1But(String firstText, String title, String secondText, String buttonText,
                                   View.OnClickListener listener, int titleColor, int secondTextColor){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_with_1_button);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        TextView firstTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogFirstText1);
        TextView secondTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogSecondText1);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle1);
        titleTextView.setTextColor(titleColor);
        secondTextView.setTextColor(secondTextColor);

        firstTextView.setText(firstText);
        secondTextView.setText(secondText);
        titleTextView.setText(title);

        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton1);
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button.setText(buttonText);
        return dialog;
    }
```

Сам диалог имеет следующую разметку:

```
<com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:realtimeBlurRadius="10dp"
    app:realtimeOverlayColor="#88e9e9e9" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle1"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogFirstText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogSecondText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_but_background"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

По сути, он должен блюрить все что под ним. Так и происходит, но диалог имеет ширину, меньшую ширины экрана. Из-за этого по бокам появляются некрасивые полосы. Как фиксить? Уже пробовал изменять размеры диалога, ничего не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением следующего кода в метод создания фрагмента:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp=dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.width=MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Весь конечный код, в итоге, выглядит так

```
private Dialog setDialogWith1But(String firstText, String title, String secondText, String buttonText,
                                   View.OnClickListener listener, int titleColor, int secondTextColor){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_with_1_button);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp=dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.width=MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        TextView firstTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogFirstText1);
        TextView secondTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogSecondText1);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle1);
        titleTextView.setTextColor(titleColor);
        secondTextView.setTextColor(secondTextColor);

        firstTextView.setText(firstText);
        secondTextView.setText(secondText);
        titleTextView.setText(title);

        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton1);
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button.setText(buttonText);
        return dialog;
    }
```